# Rails routing issue, can't figure out the link path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let me fair from the outset, and tell you that I've 'solved' the problem I'm describing. But a solution that you don't understand is not really a solution, now is it?

I have a resource, Newsbites. I have an index page for Newsbites. All my CRUD actions work fine.

I created a separate index (`frontindex.html.erb`) that acts as the front page of my website to show the newest Newsbites. The formatting is different from my normal index so readers get a larger photo, more of the text of the article(more ads too:).

In my routing table, I have the following statements:

```
 resources :newsbites
 get 'newsbites/frontindex'
 root 'newsbites#frontindex'
```

Rake routes show the following:

```
newsbites_frontindex GET    /newsbites/frontindex(.:format)   newsbites#frontindex
```

If I load my website from the root (localhost:3000), it works great. There is a separate menu page that is rendered at the top, and it loads fine. I can click on all links, except the '`Home`' link, and they work fine.

The 'Home' link is:

```
 <%= link_to 'Home', newsbites_frontindex_path %>
```

When I click on the linked, I get the following error:

```
Couldn't find Newsbite with 'id'=frontindex
```

The error points to the '`show`' action of my Newbites controller. Here are the `frontindex` and show def from the controller. They appear exactly as I'm posting them:

```
  def frontindex
  @newsbites = Newsbite.all
  end


  def show
   @newsbite = Newsbite.find(params[:id])
  end
```

I don't get it. Why is the show action being called by `newbites_frontindex_path` when there is both a def and views that match? Now, I can get around this by simply pointing home to `root_path`. But that doesn't help me understand. What if this was not the root of the site?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I'm very surprised your code worked at all. A route must define two things

- Some sort of regex against which the URL of the user is matched (`newsbites/frontindex` is different than `newsbites/backindex`)
- What do you want to do for a given URL ? You want to point to a controller action

Rails won't usually "guess" what that action is. Or maybe, he was still able to "guess" that you wanted to use the `newsbites` controller, but it didn't guess the action right this time :(.

You should declare the root like this, which is what you did

```
root 'controller#action'
```

For the rest, there are two ways you can declare it. I prefer the second one

```
resources :newsbites
get 'newsbites/frontindex', to: 'newsbites#frontindex'

resources :newsbites do
  # stuff added here will have the context of the `newsbites` controller already
  get 'frontindex', on: :collection # the name of the action is inferred to be `frontindex`
end
```

The `on: :collection`, means that 'frontindex' is an action that concerns ALL the newsbites, so the URL generated will be `newsbites/frontindex`.

On the other hand `get 'custom_action', on: :member`, means that the custom_action targets a specific item, the URL generated would look like `newsbites/:id/custom_action`

**EDIT** : Rails also generate path_helpers based on the route declaration

```
get 'test', to: 'newsbites#frontindex'
get 'test/something', to: 'newsbites#frontindex'
resources :newsbites do
      get 'frontindex', on: :collection
      get 'custom_action', on: :member
```

Will generate path helpers

```
test_path
test_something_path
# CRUD helpers : new/edit/show/delete, etc. helpers
frontindex_newsbites_path
custom_actions_newsbite_path(ID) # without s !
```

You can always override this by adding an `as:` option

```
get 'custom_action', on: :member, as: 'something_cool'
# => something_cool_newsbites_path
```

Comment: Your second route "get 'frontindex', on: :collection" worked. I had tried the first route you suggested, it didn't work. I also had to change the path in the link to frontindex_newbites_path. Thank you Cyril! I still don't understand why rails has to 'guess' what action I am trying when I have defined a 'frontindex' action in the controller.

Comment: You could very well have several routes (URLs) pointing to the same action on the same controller ! Some people want to have "user-friendly" URLs, but "programmer-friendly" action names and path helpers (which is totally legit). I will modify my answer to add default path helpers generated, maybe you're using a bad one...

Answer (score 0):

Rails routes thinks that `frontindex` is an id. That's what the error message says. So it goes to `GET newsbite/:id` which maps to `show`.

You need to find a way let Rails routes know that `frontindex` is not an `id`.

On a side note: The order in which you define routes matters. The first one matched will be used. If you have `GET newsbite/:id` and `GET newsbite/frontindex` then the one that appears first will be matched. In your case this is the first one.
Maybe try to change the order.